# How do I make these wordpress configurations?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a static website with wordpress and need to know

1. How to remove comments function
2. How to remove RSS subscribe
3. How to remove footer that says "Theme: Tarski by Ben Eastaugh and Chris Sternal-Johnson. 
   Blog at WordPress.com"
4. Select a theme that matches my structure.

The URL is http://eddaconsult.wordpress.com
How can I do it? Does it depend on the theme? Should I make my own theme instead and leave out comments, RSS subscribe and footer? What do you recommend?

Thank you

Comment: :D you sure are asking for too much. I don't think you can edit themes on wordpress.com. Maybe you mean a self-hosted WordPress?

Comment: I understand. I wanted to do it hosted by wordpress. It's possible to edit the CSS but that's either a test and paid feature and I even think that I'm referring to wht's in the php files.

Comment: Massively late downvote (OK, not really) for wanting to remove me from the footer. :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnaly to do what you want, i will create a new wordpress theme based on the default wordpress theme or another to make more easier :

- without comments loop/form (or desactivate in the back office)
- my own name in the footer :)

To remove RSS subscribe, in your functions.php :

```
automatic_feed_links(false);
```

May be to help you to choose a good theme to start your work go on http://themeforest.net/ and edit it :p

Comment: Thanks! But is it even possible without hosting wordpress yourself? I'm only using the hosting from wordpress.com

Comment: Hosting your blog from wordpress.com but why ? Wordpress is easy to install in a few steps :) I don't know what you can do on wordpress.com but if you can upload a theme it was possible to do what you want :)

Comment: Why: To not worry about for instance an extra password to the database and to abstract away hosting details like operating system choice etc.

Comment: @NiklasR yeah but if you take a shared hosting you can manage all what you want on it, without operating system choice and boring choice :)